# @isTest for a Custom Controller and Object

Tags: unit-test

I have written a Custom Controller and VF page that is launched by a custom button. The logic updates a custom object (Resource__c).  The navigation and updates work fine.  But I can't get my Test class to work.  The Test class runs successfully, but the Overall Code Coverage (in the Developer Console) for the Controller class remains 0.
I'm trying to add these components to a package and it requires the Test.  I've researched this quite a bit and I don't understand how the Test Class/method is associated to the Controller Class.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Custom Button:

```
/apex/Test_NewResource_Page?retURL={!PT_PIPROJ__Project__c.Id}&Project_ID={!PT_PIPROJ__Project__c.Id}
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class MyTestResourceController {

Resource__c record {get;set;}

public MyTestResourceController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {   

    record = (Resource__c) stdController.getRecord();
    record.Project__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Project_ID');
}
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Resource__c" extensions="MyTestResourceController" showHeader="true"> 

  <p><apex:image url="/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015i0000009iMCK&oid=00Di0000000bSEq&lastMod=1459384439000" width="31" height="31"/><font size="5"><font face="Arial">New Resource</font></font></p>

       <body>
        <div align="Left">

        </div> 
</body>  
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Resource Edit" mode="edit">
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="2">    
          <apex:outputField value="{!Resource__c.Project__c}" /> 
  <apex:inputField value="{!Resource__c.Resource_Type__c}" label="Resource Type" required="true"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Resource__c.Resource__c}" label="Resource" required="true"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Resource__c.Update_Project_Insight__c}"/>
  <apex:outputField value="{!Resource__c.PI_ProjectID__c}"/>


    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest

public class MyTestResourceControllerTests{

public static testmethod void MyResourceController_test01(){
String ProjAcct='001i000000IoBuH';
Datetime ProjSchedStart=Datetime.newInstance(1960, 2, 17);

Project__c project = new Project__c(PT_PIPROJ__Account__c=ProjAcct,PT_PIPROJ__Schedule_Start_Date__c=ProjSchedStart);    

insert project;
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Project_ID', project.Id);  


String ResType = 'Project Manager';
String ResID = '003i000000Ds1Oo';
Boolean UPDPI = False;
String PIProjID = 'PI_ID: ABCDEFG';

Resource__c record = new Resource__c(Project__c=project.Id,   Resource_Type__c=ResType, Resource__c=ResID, Update_Project_Insight__c=UPDPI,   PI_ProjectID__c=PIProjID);

Insert Record;


   // Retrieve the new Resource
 record = [SELECT Resource__c FROM Resource__c WHERE Id =:Record.Id];
   System.debug('Resource Inserted: ' + Record.Resource__c);

   // Test that the Resource correctly updated.
  System.assertEquals('003i000000Ds1Oo', record.Resource__c);
```

}
}

Comment: You need to actually create your controller and call the methods on it. [This article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm) explains the process.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120427

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65444

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53150

Comment: Thanks. I've worked through this article but am apparently missing something.  I have created my controller.  But I don't understand your comment 'call the methods on it'.  The Test Class is a separate class from the controller.  In the example of the article, I don't see how the Controller is referenced by the Test Class.

Comment: You never created a new `MyTestResourceController` in your unit test. If you don't call your code, you can't get coverage. I've provided a few questions that are probably duplicates; any of them should demonstrate how you'd go about testing.

Comment: Thanks, I will work through your recommendations and respond.

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually create the data ie the Project and the Resource object.
Check out https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_data and Google.  You shouldn't be hardcoding those ids

```
Project__c project = new Project__c();    
insert project;

ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Project_ID', project.Id);    

MyTestResourceController controller = new MyTestResourceController();
```

Then you can do stuff like

```
controller.AMethodInYourClass();
```

This is super rough but I think you will get the idea

Comment: the controller is a standard controller extension so the constructor has a different signature than your example - and is on Resource__c, not Project__c

Comment: I've modified my test class as follows.  It runs clean, but I still don't get coverage on my controller.  'Overall Code Coverage' = 0%.  I get an error when I try to use: MyTestResourceController = new MyTestResourceController()

Comment: I've modified my test class as follows.  It runs clean, but I still don't get coverage on my controller.  'Overall Code Coverage' = 0%.  I get an error when I try to use: MyTestResourceController controller = new MyTestResourceController(); Compile Error: Invalid constructor syntax, name=value pairs can only be used for SObjects.

Comment: @isTest
public class MyTestResourceControllerTests{
public static testmethod void MyResourceController_test01(){

String ProjAcct='001i000000IoBuH';

Project__c project = new Project__c(PT_PIPROJ__Account__c=ProjAcct;    
insert project;
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Project_ID', project.Id);  
  

String ResType = 'Project Manager';
String ResID = '003i000000Ds1Oo';
Resource__c record = new Resource__c (Project__c=project.Id);

Insert Record;}
}